# Creating DateTime from pattern provided by intl extension PHP

Tags: php, datetime, locale, intl

I have a project where date could be entered in different formats by locale for example:

english format: `17/04/2017`

korean format  `17. 4. 24.`
I get this data as a string in php.
I need this string to be converted to DateTime object somehow. when I have only this string value, locale and the DateType and TimeType values for `IntlDateFormatter`.
The problem that I can't use the \DateTime::createFromFormat() function because the `IntlDateFormatter::getPattern()` for the english date returns `dd/MM/y` which is not supported format by DateTime object (it should be `d/m/Y`)

sample code I have:

```
$locale = 'en_GB';
$value = '17/04/2017';     
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$format = $formatter->getPattern();
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat(format, $value);
```

From this code block i get `$dateTime = false`

Comment: `\DateTime::createFromFormat(format`? Is it? Maybe `$format`?

Comment: the problem is that IntlDateFormatter returns wrong format. DateTime doesnt support it.

Comment: Why is `17. 4. 24.` in this question? When its comes to php its all about `17/04/2017`? And use it like this `$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', $value); print $dateTime->format('d-m-y');//17-04-17`

Comment: the thing is why `17. 4. 24.` here it's because a lot of different locales could be used. and for different locales different formats are used. I get a date as a string in one format. I get a locale for the submitted date. but I cant create DateTime from it.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it is probably to late for the answer, but in case someone else also stuck with it here is the solution: Instead of using **getPattern** method, use **parse** on formater, it will return the timestamp, and you will be able to create DateTime object from it.
Ex:

```
$locale = 'en_GB';
$value = '17/04/2017';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE);

$timestamp = $formatter->parse($value);
assert($timestamp !== false);
$dateTime = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```